# Branches above each other in a phylogenetic tree

Tags: tikz-trees, forest, trees

I have created the following phylogenetic tree of the Semitic languages:
[image]

With the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
  font=\normalfont,
  minimum height=0.8cm,
  l sep+=15pt,
  inner sep=2pt,
  draw=none,
  fill=none,
  edge={draw=black, line width=0.5pt},
  anchor=north,
  child anchor=north,
  parent anchor=south,
  align=center,
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-8pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
}
[\textsc{central-semitic} 
  [\textsc{arabic} 
    [Classical\\ /r/]
    [Levantine\\ /r/ /r\textsuperscript{ʕ}/]
    [Egyptian\\ /r/ /r\textsuperscript{ʕ}/]
  ]
  [\textsc{northwest-semitic} 
    [\textsc{aramaic} 
      [Biblical\\ /ɾ/]
      [Targumic\\ /ɾ/]
      [Syriac\\ /ɾ/]
      [{Jewish Babylonian}\\ /ɾ/]
      [\textsc{nena}\\ /ɾ/ /r/ /r\textsuperscript{ʕ}/ /ɻ/]
      [Neo-Mandaic\\ /r/ /ɹ/]
      [\d{T}uroyo-Mla\d{h}so\\ /r/]
      [\textsc{wna}\\ /r/]
    ]
    [\textsc{canaanite} 
      [Phoenician\\ /r/]
      [{Samaritan Hebrew}\\ /r/]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{Central-Semitic phylogeny with rhotics}
\label{fig:semitic_tree}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I would like the node labelled "Arabic" not to be above the "Aramaic" branch, but to the left of it, with its tips at the same level of the Aramaic's and Canaanite's tips (basically, the tree should be ultrametric). How can I achieve it?

Comment: Use of the `edges` library would make this simpler as it provides the `forked edges` style.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can annotate nodes with a `tier` value to force them to be at the same level in the tree. Here I've added `tier=aramaic` (the name is arbitrary) to both the `aramaic` node and the `arabic` node to achieve the configuration you're looking for. (I also removed `tikz-qtree` from the preamble, since it's not being used and added `adjustbox` and  `libertine`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{libertine} 


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
  font=\normalfont,
  minimum height=0.8cm,
  l sep+=15pt,
  inner sep=2pt,
  draw=none,
  fill=none,
  edge={draw=black, line width=0.5pt},
  anchor=north,
  child anchor=north,
  parent anchor=south,
  align=center,
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-8pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
}
[\textsc{central-semitic} 
  [\textsc{arabic},tier=aramaic
    [Classical\\ /r/]
    [Levantine\\ /r/ /r\textsuperscript{ʕ}/]
    [Egyptian\\ /r/ /r\textsuperscript{ʕ}/]
  ]
  [\textsc{northwest-semitic} 
    [\textsc{aramaic},tier=aramaic 
      [Biblical\\ /ɾ/]
      [Targumic\\ /ɾ/]
      [Syriac\\ /ɾ/]
      [{Jewish Babylonian}\\ /ɾ/]
      [\textsc{nena}\\ /ɾ/ /r/ /r\textsuperscript{ʕ}/ /ɻ/]
      [Neo-Mandaic\\ /r/ /ɹ/]
      [\d{T}uroyo-Mla\d{h}so\\ /r/]
      [\textsc{wna}\\ /r/]
    ]
    [\textsc{canaanite} 
      [Phoenician\\ /r/]
      [{Samaritan Hebrew}\\ /r/]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{Central-Semitic phylogeny with rhotics}
\label{fig:semitic_tree}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I forgot to include `\usepackage{adjustbox}` in my code. Anyway, it works now, so thanks a lot!